# What's the most effective storage solution for x-wing to keep bases, dials and templates next to ships?

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

I have a small x-wing collection, which consists of 2 base sets, 1 of everything in waves 1, 2 and 3, 1 of each "aces" set and a couple of other small ships.

I am looking for a storage solution which will:

1. Store **all** these ships in one or more boxes.
2. Store them safely in transit, so that the paint doesn't chip/scratch
3. Store the base, 4 base templates and manoeuvre dial in the **same compartment as** or **directly next to** the model
4. Can be purchased at a **reasonable price** in the **UK**.

Most of the popular solutions I see violate one or more of these principles, particularly number 3 - which is vitally important to me because I'm sick of digging through boxes looking for the relevant cardboard when setting up.

Is there anything that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 6):

What I use is a large organizer box.  Something like this
[image]

The trick being having one where the size of the spaces can be adjusted, and one deep enough to fit the ships.

Then I cut up the original packaging of the ships.  They are already perfectly molded to the shape of the ship.  Cutting them out in exact size of the square that I am going to use I insert the packaging into he box, and then the ship into the packaging

I keep the cardboard for the ships in logical squares below the model

Comment: You can also fit a dial and two base tokens quite nicely  into the original packaging of expansion ships if you line up the void in the tokens with the hinge on the dial and slide it in right.

Answer (score 4):

I uses cases from [KR Multicase](https://www.krmulticase.com/buyarmystorage.aspx?system=STAR&army=XW) for all my X-Wing and Warhammer models. They do a selection of cases with foam inserts specifically designed for X-Wing and have cases ranging from aluminium, cardboard and backpacks.

They do pre-cut foam for most of the bigger ships as well as a standard slot which fits most of the fighters. Some of the trays in their bundles also have slots for cards/tokens:

[image]

I've found them to be very good quality.

Answer (score -5):

Check these ones http://us.battlefoam.com/star-wars-x-wing/
They look pretty good.

Comment: To people who have flagged this as spam: this question explicitly asked for product recommendations, and while this answer may not be as well-written and detailed as other answers, it's fundamentally no different.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Cascabel. 
Yeah, I'm not even affiliated with the guys from battlefoam... This is what I bought to keep my ships next to dials. I like it because it is foam and not hard surface. 
So many haters.... Was I supposed to write a 5 page document of why I like this product?

Comment: Answers that include more explanation (e.g. a couple sentences about what you like about it, or any downsides you've noticed) are definitely better; "not spam" is a relatively low bar of answer quality to clear.